# What would be a way to convert a csv file to json WITHOUT using avroSchema or ConvertRecord Processors in Apache NIFi?

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

So I had made a workflow in ApacheNifi that extracted email attachements and converted the csv files into json files. I used *InferAvroSchema* to *ConvertRecord* to convert the csv into json. Everything works well until I get a csv file that does not follow the avroschema I had written. Now I need to find a way to convert csv to json without using these two processors as the csv formatting will vary from time to time. The csv Format I currently am working with I will link below.

I have tried to extractText but I am having trouble writing the correct regex to extract the values that match their headers. I also tried *AttriutesToJson* but it seems like it is not reading the desired attributes. I know I can specify which attributes to pull but since the headers/values will be changing constantly, I can't seem to find a way to set it up dynamically.[Current CSV format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PmaG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using NiFi 1.9.2+, you can use a `CsvReader` which automatically infers schema on a per-flowfile basis. As the `JsonRecordSetWriter` can use the embedded inferred schema to write out the JSON as well, you no longer need an explicit Avro schema to be pre-defined.

As long as all the *lines* of CSV in a single flowfile follow the same schema, you won't have any problems. If you can have different schemas in the same flowfile (which I suspect would cause many additional problems as well), you'll have to filter them first into separate flowfiles.

Comment: Awesome! I was able to configure both those Controller Services to output a json. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing a script using the executeStreamCommand processor?

And more specifically, are you talking about the headers being different? There are options in the ConvertRecord processors to include headers

Comment: My issue with ConvertRecord is that it requires you to write an avroschema format to be used for the csvreader and jsonrecordsetwriter. If i use any given format, it will not run if the format is different from the csv files. Both headers and input changes. So I need a way to take any format of csv and make it a json. Also I wanted to avoid writing a script if possible.